# Render components on index.html page

Tags: reactjs

- I have created some components using react. Now i need to render
  those components on my index.html page when i click on menu bar
  options on index.html page.

  1.On index.html page  created below menu items:
  [image]

  2. I have created **home.js**,**service.js**,**about.js**,**contactUs.js** components.
     Now i need when i click Home option then render
     home.js,when i click About options render about.js.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need a routing solution have you had a look at React-Router [React-Router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router)

Answer (score 1):

Create the path required using React-router
**e.g. in routes.js** define **routes** for your application

```
module.exports = (
       <Route path="/" component={App}>
           <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
           <Route path="/services" component={Services}/>
           <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
           <Route path="/contact" component={ContactUs}/>
       </Route>
)
```

Create an entry point for your app lets say **index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router,browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}/>
  , document.querySelector('.init')
);
```

This will render react components to `.init` div or whatever you name it in your **index.html**